# how to create a new columns with random values in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I tried to initialize new columns with random values in pandas. I did this way

`df['business_vertical'] = np.random.choice(['Retail', 'SME', 'Cor'], df.shape[0])`

How do I do it in pyspark?

Comment: you want to populate "business_vertical" with a value either from "Retail", "SME", or "Cor" following a Uniform distribution ?

Comment: yes i want to populate randomly these values

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just generate a list of values and then extract them randomly :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df.withColumn(
  "business_vertical",
  F.array(
    F.lit("Retail"),
    F.lit("SME"),
    F.lit("Cor"),
  ).getItem(
    (F.rand()*3).cast("int")
  )
)
```

Comment: what is the meaning of F? i got error while trying ur code

Comment: still i got unexpected EOF while parsing error and couldn't figure out

Comment: "cannot resolve '`Retail`' given input columns: this error occured

Comment: Smart solution!! Any idea how to do this when instead of `['Retail', 'SME', 'Cor']` a small list, I have a much bigger list? how to create an PySpark array column from this list without typing them out one by one?

Comment: @ZilongZ you put your list in a dataframe, assign a row number, then do a join on a random value.

Comment: @Steven, anything on top of your mind if I want to pass a distribution of values for column, e.g. 
`'Retail' 50%, 'SME' 30%, 'Cor' 20%`

Comment: @Danish you can use a list with 5 retail, 3 sme, 2 cor and choose over 10. Works fine with this test case but probably not the best solution.

Comment: @Steven yeah looks fine for example. I had a bit complex distribution. not ideal but good enough.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can solve this with the `array_choice` function in [quinn](https://github.com/MrPowers/quinn/):

```py
import quinn

df = spark.createDataFrame([('a',), ('b',), ('c',)], ['letter'])
cols = list(map(lambda c: F.lit(c), ['Retail', 'SME', 'Cor']))
df.withColumn('business_vertical', quinn.array_choice(F.array(cols))).show()
```

```
+------+-----------------+
|letter|business_vertical|
+------+-----------------+
|     a|              SME|
|     b|           Retail|
|     c|              SME|
+------+-----------------+
```

`array_choice` is generic and can easily be used to select a random value from an existing ArrayType column.  Suppose you have the following DataFrame.

```
+------------+
|     letters|
+------------+
|   [a, b, c]|
|[a, b, c, d]|
|         [x]|
|          []|
+------------+
```

Here's how you can grab a random letter.

```py
actual_df = df.withColumn(
    "random_letter",
    quinn.array_choice(F.col("letters"))
)
actual_df.show()
```

```
+------------+-------------+
|     letters|random_letter|
+------------+-------------+
|   [a, b, c]|            a|
|[a, b, c, d]|            d|
|         [x]|            x|
|          []|         null|
+------------+-------------+
```

Here's the `array_choice` function definition:

```py
def array_choice(col):
    index = (F.rand()*F.size(col)).cast("int")
    return col[index]
```

This [post](https://mungingdata.com/pyspark/random-values-arrays-columns/) explains fetching random values from PySpark arrays in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

For random number:

```
import random
randomnum= random.randint(1000,9999)
```

or [numpy.random.choice](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
val newdf = df.withColumn("newcol",lit("your-random"))
```

or: [pandas.Series.combine_first](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html)

```
s1 = pd.Series([1, np.nan])
s2 = pd.Series([3, 4])
s1.combine_first(s2)
```

Comment: He does not want to initialize with random numbers. he wants to initialize `business_vertical` column with values from a list like `['Retail', 'SME', 'Cor']`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use pyspark.sql.functions.rand()

```
df.withColumn('rand_col', F.rand()).show()
```

Comment: Wrong answer. he wants to initialize `business_vertical` column with values from `['Retail', 'SME', 'Cor']` randomly!

Comment: yes i wants to initialize business_vertical column with values from ['Retail', 'SME', 'Cor'] randomly!